# Ajaxify Form That Submits To Same Page To Display Post Data

Tags: ajax, forms

I have a drop down menu that submits one of several filter options. The options are submitted to the same page, where post titles are displayed based on these options.
The form is working fine, but I want to make it AJAX, to only load the post titles, not the rest of the page.

The only answers/tutorials I've found deal with submitted e-mails, or forms to ANOTHER page, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it on the same page.

(This is WP specific because i know wordpress has a built-in AJAX functionality)